# Create a custom Sink in apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using apache beam and trying to Create a custom sink , unfortunately cannot find any guides on how to create a custom sink .Can someone guide.

Previously in Dataflow i used to override the Sink available in 
`com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Sink`

I cannot seem to find a similar  calls in Beam.Is it still avialble in beam somewhere?

I am using beam 2.3 sdk and Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/authoring-overview/ and see implementation of the other `write()` transforms included with the Beam SDK.

The `Sink` interface has been deleted because we have found that there are no cases where it provides any value over just implementing a composite transform made up of ParDo, GBK and other transforms. Please also see [this recent talk of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhj4Bjczb8I) ([slides](https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/269/Radically%20modular%20data%20ingestion%20APIs%20in%20Apache%20Beam%20Presentation.pdf)) about IO in Beam and about why sources/sinks should not be a special API, but should be simply composite transforms.

Comment: @Eugene can you provide any sample code example for creating and using custom Sink and Source?

Comment: Nearly all IO classes in Beam are "custom", so you can just look at their source code https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io